# Error When Handling Json Data From API Get Request

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I am trying to access an int value from the key "market_cap_rank", within the first json object. the code below auto aborts the program and return "exited with code 3."

also when i parsed the "r.text" ive noticed that it gives me entirly different json data!

```
#include <cpr/cpr.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
#include <string>

// for convenience
using json = nlohmann::json;

using namespace cpr;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    auto v = Get(Url{ "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/search?query=bitcoin" });
    json data = json::parse(v.text);
    cout << "Rank: " << data["coins"]["market_cap_rank"] << endl;
    
}
```

I was expecting for the output to be "Rank: 1"

Comment: Print out `v.text` ... What exactly does it contain?

Comment: {"coins":[{"id":"bitcoin","name":"Bitcoin","api_symbol":"bitcoin","symbol":"BTC","market_cap_rank":1,"thumb":"https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/thumb/bitcoin.png","large":"https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/large/bitcoin.png"},{"id":"wrapped-bitcoin","name":"Wrapped Bitcoin","api_symbol":"wrapped-bitcoin","symbol":"WBTC","market_cap_rank":22,"thumb":"https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/7598/thumb/wrapped_bitcoin_wbtc.png","large":"https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/7598/large/wrapped_bitcoin_wbtc.png"},... output extends further but this gives u an idea.

Comment: Well, coins is a list / array, so `data["coins"]["market_cap_rank"]` doesn't make sense. PS: you should edit the question to include that information, as opposed to as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, the issue is that `data["coins"]` is in fact a list of object; thus, `data["coins"]["market_cap_rank"]` does not make sense. You probably want to do:

```cpp
for ( json &item : data["coins"] ) {
    std::cout << "Item with id " << item["id"] 
              << " has market cap rank of " << item["market_cap_rank"] << '\n';
}
```